# Parse Apache logs for specific verbiage within the last hour

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, log-files, grep

I'm looking to parse my `/var/log/httpd` folder which contains a lot of Apache log files.

I'm looking for specific events within the last hour. I've tried the below, but I didn't have any luck.

`grep -R "$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" /var/log/httpd/ | grep "too many failed"`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a recursive grep (-R) - which is useless in this case- I presume you don't have any subdirs under /var/log/httpd (if that's standard distro).

What you want to do is discard everything before a line that has timestamp from hour ago. Also, access and error logs typically have different timestamps in them.

So, for example, access log has the following timestamp:

```
[15/Jun/2014:23:11:41 +0200]
```

So you need to use date to print time in that specific timestamp, for example:

```
CURTIME=$(date -d -1hour +'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M' | sed 's#/#.#g'); \
sed "1,/$CURTIME/d" /var/log/httpd/*access_log
```

For error log, you need to use different approach, because error_log uses this kind of timestamp:

```
[Sat Jun 14 09:12:50 2014]
```

Only thing you may bear in mind is that if apache didn't log any line an hour ago, this approach would fail because there wouldn't be a line match for sed.

Comment: This is a great start, thanks! I'm getting output that I can work with.

Comment: you need to add a test about the limit of time. The sed action take all the file if not specific event occur ath this time. So first test with a grep -c to be sur at least 1 line could be catch as the limit

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the format of the dates in you apache logs ? On the systems I have to hand (CentOS) that have their access logs in `/var/log/httpd` the date format is

```
15/Jun/2014:11:48:27 +0000
```

If yours is the same then you need

```
date -d -1hour +'%d/%b/%Y:%H'
```

as your date command.

If it's different then you need to show us the format that the log file is using.